# Add XElement only if value exists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm creating an XDocument using Linq-To-XML, like this:

```
Order order = GetOrder();

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("purchaseOrder",
        new XElement("Name", order.Name),
        new XElement("Address", order.Address),
        new XElement("Shipper", order.Shipper)
    )
);
```

So sometimes an order will not have a Shipper, it will be null. In that case, I don't want to include the Shipper element at all.

How can I do that inline in my code when creating the doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would form the xml in parts instead of forming all of it at once. (*easier to read, easier to debug*)

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();

var order = new XElement("purchaseOrder",
                new XElement("Name", order.Name),
                new XElement("Address", order.Address));

if(order.Shipper!=null) order.Add(new XElement("Shipper", order.Shipper));

doc.Add(order);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check if the `Shipper` value is null.  If it isn't, then add your element, otherwise just set it to null.  A null value in the constructor translates to nothing added in its place.

```
Order order = GetOrder();

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("purchaseOrder",
        new XElement("Name", order.Name),
        new XElement("Address", order.Address),
        order.Shipper != null ? new XElement("Shipper", order.Shipper) : null
    )
);
```

Comment: Good answer.  And if you need to add the element even if the data is not available, you could use:   order.Shipper != null ? new XElement("Shipper", order.Shipper) : new XElement("Shipper", "")

Answer (score 1):

I would have something like this:

```
Order order = GetOrder();

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("purchaseOrder",
        new XElement("Name", order.Name),
        new XElement("Address", order.Address),
        OptionalXElement("Shipper", order.Shipper)
    )
);
```

Sometimes I have a subclass of XElement anyway (to automatically prepend a namespace), and add the static helper to it:

```
MyXElement.CreateIfNeeded("Shipper", order.Shipper);
```